# Sveltekit "Error: Not found" error after refactoring

Tags: sveltekit

I've refactored the `lib` folder from this (files in `src/lib/scss`):

[before refactor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcxs7.png)

to this (files moved out of `src/lib/scss` to `src/lib`):

[after refactor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZZOm.png)

and updated the imports accordingly. The imports look like this (one of the files that included this was `routes/+layout.svelte`):

```
<script>
    import '$lib/app.scss'
</script>
```

Still, every few times I reload a page there is this error in my terminal:

```
Error: Not found: /src/lib/scss/app.scss
    at resolve (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:397:13)
    at resolve (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:246:5)
    at Object.#options.hooks.handle (/@fs/[work directory]/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:43:56)
    at Module.respond(/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:243:40)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

`src/lib/scss/form.scss` is a file that I've moved somewhere else in `lib`. However, Sveltekit still seems to remember that there was a file there and tries to find it. Most of the time, the page still renders completely fine without any errors in the browser console. This happens even if the files responsible for the error aren't imported by the page I'm viewing.

I'm not integrating Sveltekit with anything else, the only install commands I've run are for Sveltekit and Sass.

I've made sure to update every import statement in my `src` folder files to the new locations and tried to delete the `.svelte-kit` folder with no apparent effect. I've tried moving everything in the `routes` folder except for a single blank `+page.svelte` but the problem got even worse (Sveltekit starts complaining about every single file ever that I've moved out of `routes`).

Comment: I am not sure, but if you have something that is like a file watcher, stoping it and relaunching might fix the issue.

Comment: Other than Sveltekit's npm run dev I haven't used any other file watchers. Even after restarting my computer the problem persists.

Comment: It would make sense that you also describe your import statements (including in which file you do the import). Also make sure to use `<style lang="scss">` where you import

Comment: ok, edited. Also for anyone facing the same problem I just copied the src folder into another fresh Sveltekit project and didn't move any files from their current location. Not a fix tho since you'll have to remember not to shift any files.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)